# socket.io event on reconnect timeout

Tags: javascript, websocket, socket.io, reconnect

I am using socket.io to do websocket communication within my application.
After the connection is lost, it tries to reconnect 6 times, then it reaches a timeout.
Is there any event, emitted when it is no longer trying to reconnect?

Comment: can you show your codes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I found that this is a known issue.

Reference: https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/issues/652

Sad ... :(

Answer (score 0):

From the source code it seems the event is "reconnect_failed"

```
if (this.attempts > this._reconnectionAttempts) {
this.emit('reconnect_failed');
this.reconnecting = false;
}
```

Comment: According to https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/wiki/Exposed-events you are right, but this event is never fired ... :(

**Edit:** Maybe I did not configure the amount of attempts well enough. Can anyone tell me how to do it?